# SpringBoot 2 the elements were left unbound

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a file application.yml  with my Spring Boot application which is not willing to run.

According to logs the reason of The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound. This property however is set in application.yml and compiler is even returning it's value.

I'll really appreciate if someone could lend me a hand with that issue.

```
simulator:
    geo:
        host: http://localhost:8080/
        b12: http://localhost:8080/geo/b12
        b13: http://localhost:8080/geo/b13
        b21: http://localhost:8080/geo/b21
        c6: http://localhost:8080/geo/c6
```

and java class

```
@Getter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "simulator",ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class VendorSimulatorProperties {

    @Value("${simulator.geo.host:http://localhost:8080/}")
    private String initUrl;

    @Value("${simulator.geo.b12}")
    private String geoB12Url;

    @Value("${simulator.geo.b13}")
    private String geoB13Url;

    @Value("${simulator.geo.b21}")
    private String geoB21Url;

    @Value("${simulator.geo.c6}")
    private String geoC6Url;
}
```

when i start to run application, i got the error msg :

```
**************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@1c140c7c type = com.mathartsys.dlc.thirdparty.vendor.config.VendorSimulatorProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eb0a550b, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties(prefix=simulator, value=simulator, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreInvalidFields=false)]] failed:

    Property: simulator.geo.b12
    Value: http://localhost:8080/geo/b12
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:204:14
    Reason: The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound.
    Property: simulator.geo.b13
    Value: http://localhost:8080/geo/b13
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:205:14
    Reason: The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound.
    Property: simulator.geo.b21
    Value: http://localhost:8080/geo/b21
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:206:14
    Reason: The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound.
    Property: simulator.geo.c6
    Value: http://localhost:8080/geo/c6
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:207:13
    Reason: The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound.
    Property: simulator.geo.host
    Value: http://localhost:8080/
    Origin: class path resource [config/application-dev.yml]:203:15
    Reason: The elements [simulator.geo.b12,simulator.geo.b13,simulator.geo.b21,simulator.geo.c6,simulator.geo.host] were left unbound.
```

this problem had confuse me long time, i hope someone can give me some advice; 
i used springboot 2.0
thanks

Comment: You are using `@ConfigurationProperties` in a wrong way. You either use `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Value` but not both. Remove the `@ConfigurationProperties` as it doesn't add anything here nor does your structure adhere to the conventions needed for this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `@ConfigurationProperties` in a wrong way. You use either `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Value` but not both.

The solution either fix your class to be usable for `@ConfigurationProperties` or remove the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "simulator.geo",ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class VendorSimulatorProperties {

    private String host = "http://localhost:8080/";
    private String b12;
    private String b13;
    private String b21;
    private String c6;

}
```

You need to fix the `prefix` it should be `simulator.geo` and your properties should be named after the keys in your file. You will also require setter next to the getter. However this will also need to change the rest of your configuration, to use the newly generated getters.

For you it is probably easier to remove `@ConfigurationProperties` as you weren't really using them in the first place.

Comment: I do the same but still get same issue. Actually i use @PostConstruct for create default folder on startup.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel please add No Arg constructor.

Comment: @vinodchambole you don't need the `@NoArgsConstructor` as that is added already by the compiler. There is no `@Data` and no `final` fields so the only constructor available is a no-args constructor. So your comment doesn't make any sense what so ever.

Comment: Getter is optionally, but, yes, @Setter is a must.

Comment: I face the same error, even with this configuration it still failing

Answer (score 10):

I got the same issue, but in my case, it's because I added `@AllArgsConstructor` but did not add `@NoArgsConstructor`. As the result, Spring was unable to create the config object (using the default constructor) so it just skips processing the configs and print out the warning.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor // need to add this if you have @AllArgsConstructor
public class ServerConfiguration {
    private String host;
    private int port;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the exact cause of my current issue!

Comment: Indeed, it is required if `@AllArgsContructor` is used. Since the constructor without parameters is only used by Spring, it is safer to pass it in private access: `@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try adding a Modifier "static" for your inner class.
for example:

```html
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "pvs.support.cache")
public class CacheProperties {

  List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

  @Data
  public static class Item {
    /*缓存名*/
    String name;

    /*过期时长*/
    @DurationUnit(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
    Duration ttl = Duration.ofSeconds(3600);
  }
}
```