# Reason: The elements were left unbound

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, lombok

How can I load List of objects from configuration yml file in java springboot application?

I already tried several sources:

[configuration-properties-in-spring-boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

[spring-boot-configurationproperties-example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/)

[SpringBoot 2 the elements were left unbound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167040/springboot-2-the-elements-were-left-unbound)

Stack: Java 11, SpringBoot 2.1.4, Lombok, configuration file in .yml format.

I tried to implement simple @Component, which will load data from configuration file.

Configuration values are:

```
allowed:
  - first-crossroad: ONE
    second-crossroad: TWO
    third-crossroad: TWO
    fourth-crossroad: THREE
  - first-crossroad: ONE
    second-crossroad: THREE
    third-crossroad: TWO
    fourth-crossroad: ONE
```

Java class for data loading is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")
@Data
public class AllowedCrossroads {

  private List<CrossroadCombination> allowed;
}
```

Java CrossroadCombination object definition:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CrossroadCombination {

  private String firstCrossroad;
  private String secondCrossroad;
  private String thirdCrossroad;
  private String fourthCrossroad;
}
```

I expected values to be loaded during application run. But I am getting error:

```
Property: allowed[0].first-crossroad
    Value: ONE
    Origin: class path resource [application.yml]:644:17
    Reason: The elements [allowed[0].first-crossroad,allowed[0].fourth-crossroad,allowed[0].second-crossroad,allowed[0].third-crossroad,allowed[1].first-crossroad,allowed[1].fourth-crossroad,allowed[1].second-crossroad,allowed[1].third-crossroad,allowed[2].first-crossroad,allowed[2].fourth-crossroad,allowed[2].second-crossroad,allowed[2].third-crossroad] were left unbound.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(One of many) Solution:

- add: @NoArgsConstructor

to java class:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CrossroadCombination {

  private String firstCrossroad;
  private String secondCrossroad;
  private String thirdCrossroad;
  private String fourthCrossroad;
}
```

Explanation:

It is because when we create an object, we need to have an empty object and then fill it with data. This is why we need no args constructor.

Anyway solution from "@Daniel V" is also correct and thanks for that one!

Comment: I was only using `@Data`. Adding `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Making The Inner class as static will work

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")
@Data
public class AllowedCrossroads {

    private List<CrossroadCombination> allowed;

    @Data
    public static class CrossroadCombination {
        private String firstCrossroad;
        private String secondCrossroad;
        private String thirdCrossroad;
        private String fourthCrossroad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution for me. Great~

Answer (score 4):

including Getters and Setters for all fields solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with java ResourceBundle library?

for example:

```
ResourceBundle configApp = ResourceBundle.getBundle("path to your configuration file");
```

after that you can use configApp like so:

```
configApp.getString("first-crossroad");
```

can you try that and tell me how it goes.

EDIT:

The data in your configuration file if your planning to use ResourceBundle should look like this:

```
allowed=[first-crossroad= ONE, second-crossroad= TWO, third-crossroad= TWO,fourth-crossroad= THREE,first-crossroad= ONE, second-crossroad= THREE,third-crossroad= TWO, fourth-crossroad= ONE]
```

the "[]" isn't neccesary but it makes it look more readable

then you call it like this:

configApp.getObject("allowed");

that will store it like this:

```
[first-crossroad= ONE, second-crossroad= TWO, third-crossroad= TWO,fourth-crossroad= THREE,first-crossroad= ONE, second-crossroad= THREE,third-crossroad= TWO, fourth-crossroad= ONE]
```

then you can cast this to an array or play with it like this.

Comment: And how can I use it to fill List? Because I have first-crossroad property twice, what value will this call: configApp.getString("first-crossroad"); return?

Comment: Hey man, thats an issue, but I did some test and if you wanna use resourcebundle library you gotta put your data in the configuration file like the edit im gonna post you on my answer

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a solution! But I just found, that issue is in lombok. When I add: @NoArgsConstructor to class: CrossroadCombination it works as expected. It is probably because object is initialised first and then filled with data. This is why we need this constructor. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Okay! im glad you found solution :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case the variable name is not matched. Please check all fields names and mapping configuration key names.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).